# MongoDB Sharding, config servers count

Tags: mongodb, sharding

How many config server do I need to run mongodb shard environment with 4 replicasets of 3 nodes in each?

What is the formula between shard config servers, shards and nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run MongoDB with either one or 3 config servers. For a production deployment this should always be 3 to allow for redundancy. Documentation for this is [available here.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-config-servers/#deploy-three-config-servers-for-production-deployments)